# How can I choose what settings my Windows Live account syncs between systems?

Tags: windows-8, sync, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What gets synced across computers using the same Windows Live ID?](https://superuser.com/questions/491151/what-gets-synced-across-computers-using-the-same-windows-live-id)

I have multiple Windows 8 systems and I use the same Windows Live ID for all of them.  The benefit of using a Windows Live ID is that it syncs settings between my various Windows 8 computers. But it's annoying that it syncs the same desktop picture to each system. I want a different picture on each system.

*How can I choose what settings my Windows Live account syncs between Windows 8 systems?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a Windows Live ID as your account ID for multiple Windows 8 systems, it will sync various settings between all the computers, which is beneficial in *most* cases.

However, if you prefer not to sync all or some settings, you can change this.

Go to the Start menu, type `Sync Settings` and under the 'Settings' section click "Sync your Settings".

[image]

You can choose to sync (or not) your:

- System colors, background, lock screen settings, account picture
- Desktop themes, high contrast, etc.
- Passwords, sign in info
- Ease of Access settings for Narrator, Magnifier, etc.
- Keyboard and language preferences
- App settings
- and other Windows settings for Explorer, the mouse, etc.